# Provide directory listings using API Gateway as a proxy to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to host a static site through S3 and API Gateway (using S3 directly isn't an option due to security policy).  One of the pages runs a client-side script to pull back a set of files from a specific folder on the server.  I've set up the hosting following the [Amazon tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html).

For this to run, my script needs to be able to obtain the list of files for a specific folder.

If I was hosting the site on my own server using Apache, I could rely on the directory listing feature, where a GET on a folder with no index.html returns a file list.  The tutorial suggests that this should be possible, but I can't seem to get it to work.  If I submit a request to a particular {prefix}/{identifier}, I can retrieve the specific file, but sending a request to {prefix}/ returns an error.

Is there a way I can replicate directory listings so my Javascript can pull it down and read it, or is the only solution to write a server-side API in Lambda?